# Android ContentResolver.requestSync() does not always trigger SyncAdapter immediately after it is canceled

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I have an Android app with a `SyncAdapter` which works *most* of the time. It is possible for the user to change what data set they would like to look at, which requires a resync. The user can also change the data set while the app is in the process of syncing which can cause a race condition if the user starts a sync, changes data set, and then the sync completes which leaves them looking at the wrong data.

To fix this, when the user changes data set I would like to cancel any existing sync and then trigger a new sync for the selected data set. I did this like so:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ... // Some members omitted for clarity

    // Called whenever the user changes the data set
    private void onDataSetChanged() {
        final Account account = getSelectedAccount();
        final boolean isSyncActive = ContentResolver.isSyncActive(account, AUTHORITY);

        // Cancel sync for the old data set
        Log.e(TAG, "onDataSetChanged: " + account.name + " - " + isSyncActive);
        if (isSyncActive) {
            ContentResolver.cancelSync(account, AUTHORITY);
        }

        // Request a sync for the new data set
        ContentResolver.requestSync(account, AUTHORITY, new Bundle());
    }
}
```

Elsewhere I have a `SyncAdapter` defined:

```
public class SyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {
    ... // Some members omitted for clarity

    @Override
    public synchronized void onPerformSync(final Account account, final Bundle extras,
            final String authority, final ContentProviderClient provider, final SyncResult syncResult) {
       Log.e(TAG, "onPerformSync: " + account.name);

       ... // Sync logic
   }
}
```

The `SyncAdapter` appears to be set up correctly as it is *usually* called successfully and the `#onPerformSync()` log statement appears. Only when `ContentResolver.cancelSync()` is called immediately before `ContentResolver.requestSync()`, will it *sometimes* (not always) fail. In those instances `SyncAdapter#onPerformSync()` is never called and its log statement is not displayed.

I have tried setting `ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED` and `ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL` as `true` on the extras bundle, but that has no effect. I've also verified through my own logging that the `account` and `AUTHORITY` are correct. I also see the `onPerformSync: ...` log when it does sync successfully, so I know I am not mis-using Logcat as many people working with `SyncAdapters` do.

I know requesting a sync is quite a complicated process, but is there at least some way for me to know why the sync was rejected? Other logs don't seem to indicate why it decided to ignore my request.

Comment: Did you find out why the onPerformSync was not called sometimes?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't remember a whole lot about this particular problem. I don't believe I ever found a real solution and instead just accepted the fact that `.requestSync()` is unreliable. I had to work around it by simply avoiding that method. I would call my sync code directly rather than going through `SyncAdapter` and manually track whether or not a sync was currently active.

I don't really have a solution unfortunately, I pretty much just hacked around it.

Comment: Thanks for the details response.  It looks like that there is some sort of throttling done in the Sync Adapter if some syncs don't finish correctly. Your hack sounds like a good solution too.